# Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of A Object But I Have Initiated It

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im having this weird problem developing my unity football game, it says "Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object" On The Script Ball On The Line Of 33 and 19. And also on player script on line 55 and 29. Heres My Code For Player And Ball:

Player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using StarterAssets;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private StarterAssetsInputs starterAssetsInputs;
    private Animator animator;
    private ball ballAttachedToPlayer;
    private float timeShot = -1f;
    public const int ANIMATION_LAYER_SHOOT = 1;
    
    public ball BallAttachedToPlayer { get => ballAttachedToPlayer; set => ballAttachedToPlayer = value; }
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        starterAssetsInputs = GetComponent<StarterAssetsInputs>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(starterAssetsInputs.shoot)
        {
            starterAssetsInputs.shoot = false;
            timeShot = Time.time;
            animator.Play("Shoot", ANIMATION_LAYER_SHOOT, 0f);
            animator.SetLayerWeight(ANIMATION_LAYER_SHOOT, 1f);
        }
        if(timeShot>0)
        {
            // shoot ball
            
            if(ballAttachedToPlayer != null && Time.time - timeShot > 0.2)
            {
                ballAttachedToPlayer.StickToPlayer = false;
                
                Rigidbody rigidbody = ballAttachedToPlayer.transform .gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * 20f, ForceMode.Impulse);
                
                ballAttachedToPlayer = null;
            }
            
            // finish kicking animation
            
            if (Time.time - timeShot > 0.5)
            {
                timeShot = -1f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetLayerWeight(ANIMATION_LAYER_SHOOT, Mathf.Lerp(animator.GetLayerWeight(ANIMATION_LAYER_SHOOT), 0f, Time.deltaTime * 10f));
        }
    }
}
```

Ball:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool stickToPlayer;
    [SerializeField] private Transform transformPlayer;
    [SerializeField] private Transform playerBallPosition;
    float speed;
    Vector3 previousLocation;
    Player scriptPlayer;
    
    public bool StickToPlayer { get => stickToPlayer; set => stickToPlayer = value; }
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerBallPosition = transformPlayer.Find("Geometry").Find("BallLocation");
        scriptPlayer = transformPlayer.GetComponent<Player>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!StickToPlayer)
        {
            float distanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transformPlayer.position, transform.position);
            Debug.Log(distanceToPlayer);
            if (distanceToPlayer < 0.5)
            {
                StickToPlayer = true;
                scriptPlayer.BallAttachedToPlayer = this;
            }
        
        }
        else
        {
            Vector2 currentLocation = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.z);
            speed = Vector2.Distance(currentLocation, previousLocation) / Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = playerBallPosition.position;
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(transformPlayer.right.x, 0, transformPlayer.right.z), speed, Space.World);
            previousLocation = currentLocation;
        }
    }
}
```

This Script Should Have Shot The Ball Away And Play My Kick Animation, But Instead Threw Me A Random Error.

Comment: I don't see any initialization of `transformPlayer`. Thus when line 19 throws, also `scriptPlayer` won't be initialized ...

Comment: im a total beginner in this, im following a tutorial, the tutorial didnt define transformPlayer anywhere. The Tutorial Is Called "How to create a soccer game in unity". But it worked perfectly in the video. Mind giving a idea of how to define the transformPlayer?

Comment: No offense, but if you are a total beginner you probably should get some basic programming experience before starting with something like unitiy. Because this framework has some concepts which are not easy to understand for a total beginner ... I'm not a unity guy, so I really can't help you with unitiy specific problems. But if it works in the tutorial and not for you, you probably missed ...